# Is it possible to download map layer from map server and adding it to google map?

Tags: arcgis-server, google-maps, web-service

This is a link for the base map server :

It contain about 23 layers, my question.. let say I want layer number 23 is it possible to get this layer and adding it to google map? Because I don't see on google a way to add this layer by a URL from any map server

1. I want to get this layer
2. then add it to google map

What do I need for this?

Any advice or solution for this problem?

Comment: Hey - do you mean you want to embed it into google map as part of the core data that displays on their webmap? or do you mean you want to display the data atop of the Google Map basemap as an additional layer?

Comment: Your Webmap service is calling to a Port which makes it difficult to navigate to. Do you have a URL that has a domain that does not include the port?

Comment: @MDHald I want to create my own map using  google (my map) maker and I want to add this layer from map server to the basemap , but the only way to add layer is you have to upload it as KML ,CSV ... but how to get this layer from the map server as KML file ?

Comment: @MDHald this the original website for this map http://wasef.alriyadh.gov.sa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will depend if the Service producer [has enabled KML](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/get-started/windows/tutorial-publishing-a-kml-service.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_1BC9EB3775254E1CBAF38EA743C19904), but will be the easiest way to get a KML format of the service. From here, you can add the content to your google map with no problems.

- Navigate to the ArcGIS Service Directory of the address you have (I will be using a sample ESRI server)

> https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services

- Click the service you are looking to Map( I will use demographics)
  [image]
- Click the MapServer you wish to have a KML of:

> https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer

- scroll to the bottom of the page and select "Generate KML"
  [image]
- Type in a Name, select the layers you want by using the checkboxes, determine your layer options:

[image]

when you have the KMZ file downloaded you will need to extract the KML file from it. In order to do this you will need [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

- Right Click the KMZ file and select 7-Zip>Open Archive. [image]
- In 7-Zip select the file and click Extract.

[image]

- follow the prompts and select OK. Then you can navigate to where you extracted it to and the file will be there as a KML.

[image]

Comment: first thing , thank you ... I did the same thing you did exactly but at the end I got the layers with .KMZ just like you after download it you get it kmz , so I try to upload this layer on my map but it reject it !

Comment: Ya that is one silly thing about ESRI Products. it makes a KMZ instead of a KML. ill add to the answer to explain how to get the KML from it.

Comment: I can't verify this but try: http://7zx.updatestar.com/